# Catch exact item that throws Exception in a for-each loop

Tags: java, exception

I need access to the `File` variable `f` inside my `catch` clause. How can I achieve this?

```
try { 
    for(File f:filesInDir) {
        new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f)); 
} 
catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
    System.out.println("Could not open input file "+ f +" for reading.");
}
```

Comment: Catch within the for-loop. Then you have the file. Also be sure to close the input stream after using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the `try`/`catch` block in you `for` loop like this:

```
for(File f : filesInDir) {
  try {
    new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not open input file " + f + " for reading.");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the exception by e in the catch block..Along with that, it has lot of methods which is going to be useful if you do CTRL + SPACE..
Hope it helps..